# Lost UK Passport

Tags: uk, passports, paperwork

I didn't lose mine, but I understand that new rules have been implemented that affect British travellers who lose their passports whilst abroad.

How does a British traveller who has lost their passport get a replacement passport? And secondarily, how long does it take assuming China as an indicative locale?

---

Note: this is **not** a duplicate of an existing question.

Comment: [Relevant info](https://www.gov.uk/overseas-passports/y/china/replacing/adult)

Answer (score 3):

The UK government has a web site for finding out how to replace etc. UK passports from overseas. See [Overseas British passport applications](https://www.gov.uk/overseas-passports).

I've tried it out for replacing a lost passport for an adult from several locations, and each time it indicated 6 weeks, and offers the alternative of an emergency travel document for urgent travel.